# Change WMI Security Descriptor programatically not working

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, wmi

I'm trying to change the Wmi Security Descriptor of a about 100 hundred Computers with Windows 10 Pro/DC 2012 R2.
I found that the following approach can be used in my case : [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spatdsg/2007/11/21/set-wmi-namespace-security-via-gpo-script/)

Executing the steps locally on a Windows 10 machine with the domain admin account didn't give the expected result. The export of the namespace is working as expected but the changing of the descriptor with the script have not effects at all.
The export command:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2  /output:sd.txt path __systemsecurity call getSD
```

The import script:

```
arrSD = array(1,0,4,129,148,0,0,0,164,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,2,0,128,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,1,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,5,21,0,0,0,216,37,44,114,11,95,44,7,34,199,223,9,83,4,0,0,0,18,24,0,63,0,6,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0,0,18,20,0,19,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,20,0,0,0,0,18,20,0,19,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,19,0,0,0,0,18,20,0,19,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,11,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0)

' Connect to WMI and the root namespace.

'

Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:root\CIMV2")


' Get the single __SystemSecurity object in this namespace.

'

Set objSecurity = objWMI.Get("__SystemSecurity=@")


' Change the namespace security.

'

nReturn = objSecurity.SetSD(arrSD)
```

WScript.Echo "Return value = " & nReturn
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this for all WMI access, or specific classes/namespaces?

Comment: I prefer to do it for specefic WMI namespaces but if there is no choice I can apply it to all WMI access.